# Igoear GUWIP204 wireless usb hub

Tags: usb-hub

is it possible to connect a usb hub to the wireless Iogear GUWIP204 usb hub?

my aim is to increase number of usb ports and still be able to use it by wireless anetnna.

Comment: You can chain USB hubs (with considerations on power and bandwidth, especially considering it is wireless)... and have up to 127 devices in a USB connection... Is there some reason you feel this would not work with this device?

Comment: Did you check Amazon reviews?

Answer (score 0):

This device GUWIP204 is an apparent embedded computer with USB host capabilities. As "embedded USB host", it has all rights to support a limited set of USB device classes. They are fully USB compliant as long as manufacturer provides a list of what they support.

The [manual for GUWIP204](https://www.iogear.com/support/dm/download_manual/?mnid=1061) says, on p.5:

Supported Devices:

• Printer or Multi-function printer with USB connection*

• External USB hard drive

• USB webcam*

• USB flash drive

• USB memory card reader

• USB printer

• USB scanner

Unfortunately,  USB hubs are not in the list, so you are out of luck. But it is worth to ask the ioGear support explicitly.

Comment: Also, the device uses 100Mbps WiFi link, so it's performance will be at about 1/5 of the normal USB 2.0 link.